# Ajax doesn't pass the argument

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-sortable

I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function makeSortable(selector) {
    $(selector).sortable({

        update: function(event, ui) {
                //var pagesOrder = $(selector).sortable('toArray').toString();
                var pagesOrder = $(selector).sortable('serialize',{key:'str[]'});

                alert(pagesOrder);                  
                $.get("utried.php", {poradie: pagesOrder} );

        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    makeSortable("#sortedMenu");  
});
</script>
```

and it doesn't work. 
The variable `"pagesOrder"` is alerted correctly. The ajax command should pass that variable to "utried.php" file. It doesn't. Interestingly enough, when I send {poradie: "someString"} it passes this argument. When I try to pass pagesOrder it passes empty variable "poradie" instead of that true value alerted above...

Below I attach the whole HTML I'm using...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en"><head><title>KALA Administratorska cast</title>
<meta name="publisher" content="">
<meta name="copyright" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="robots" content="follow">
<meta name="revisit-after" content="5 days">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="author" content="Mato a Samo edit by Tomy">
<link href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/kalaadmin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head><body><table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr> 
    <td width="15%">&nbsp; </td>
    <td width="70%" align="center" valign="top"> 
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr> 
          <td width="25%" height="160" align="left" valign="bottom"><img src="/imgs/kalaadminlogo.gif" width="178" height="69"></td>
          <td width="75%" valign="bottom">
<div align="right"><a class="menu" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?mysession_action=logout">ODHLÁSENIE</a></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
          <td valign="top" bgcolor="#808080"> 
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
              <tr> 
                <td bgcolor="#FF6600">HLAVNÉ MENU</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
<a class="menu" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=admin">ADMINISTRÁTOR</a>
<a class="podmenu" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=multimail">Vytvor hromadný email</a>
<a class="podmenu" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=emailtext">Obsah emailov</a>
<a class="menu" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=users">UŽÍVATELIA</a>
<a class="podmenu" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=users&amp;users_button_new=yes">Pridaj nového užívatela</a>
<a class="menu" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat">TOVAR</a>
<a class="podmenu" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;kat_button_new=yes&amp;root_id=0">Pridaj novú kategóriu tovaru</a>
<a class="podmenu" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=precentovar">Precenovanie</a>
<a class="menu" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=static">STATICKÉ STRÁNKY</a>
<a class="podmenu" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=static&amp;static_button_new=yes">Pridaj stránku</a>
<a class="podmenu" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=news">Novinky</a>
<a class="podmenu" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=zelanie">Krátka správa</a>
<a class="menu" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=objed">OBJEDNÁVKY</a>
<a class="podmenu" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=objed&amp;type=vyb">Vybavené objednávky</a>


            </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            </td>
          <td valign="top">
<form action="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="sub" value="kat">
<input type="hidden" name="root_id" value="6">

              <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
                <tr> 
<td colspan="5" bgcolor="#FF6600">TOVAR - POLOŽKA</td></tr><tr><td colspan="5"><a class="text" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;root_id=0">MERACIE PRÍSTROJE</a></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="5"><img src="/imgs/strom.gif" width="12" height="11"><a class="text" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;root_id=1">Prístroje pre revízie elektroinštalácie</a></td></tr>

                <tr> 
                  <td width="4%" class="grey">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td width="44%" class="grey" colspan="2"><span class="textb">KATEGÓRIA / TOVAR</span></td>
                </tr>
 <script src="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/javascript/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/javascript/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function spravSortable(selector) {
    $(selector).sortable({

        update: function(event, ui) {
                //var pagesOrder = $(selector).sortable('toArray').toString();
                var pagesOrder = $(selector).sortable('serialize',{key:'str[]'});
                //var pagesOrder = "tvoja pica pojebana";
                alert(pagesOrder);                  
                $.get("utried.php", {poradie: pagesOrder} );
                //.done(function(data){
                    //$("#result").html(data);
                    //alert(pagesOrder);
                //});
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    spravSortable("#sortedMenu");  
});
</script>

<tr><td colspan="5"><ul id="sortedMenu"><li id='srtable_776'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar776" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=776&amp;root_id=6">ZEROLINE 60 - presný digitální meric impedance smycky a síte</a>
</li><li id='srtable_11'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar11" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=11&amp;root_id=6">PU 182.1</a>
</li><li id='srtable_584'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar584" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=584&amp;root_id=6">PU 294 DELTA</a>
</li><li id='srtable_586'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar586" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=586&amp;root_id=6">PD 294</a>
</li><li id='srtable_12'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar12" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=12&amp;root_id=6">PU 183</a>
</li><li id='srtable_14'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar14" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=14&amp;root_id=6">PD 183</a>
</li><li id='srtable_13'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar13" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=13&amp;root_id=6">PU 193</a>
</li><li id='srtable_15'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar15" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=15&amp;root_id=6">PD 193.1</a>
</li><li id='srtable_16'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar16" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=16&amp;root_id=6">PD 193.2</a>
</li><li id='srtable_18'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar18" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=18&amp;root_id=6">PD 193.3</a>
</li><li id='srtable_19'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar19" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=19&amp;root_id=6">PU 184 Delta</a>
</li><li id='srtable_20'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar20" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=20&amp;root_id=6">PU 194 Delta</a>
</li><li id='srtable_21'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar21" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=21&amp;root_id=6">PU 194 10A Delta</a>
</li><li id='srtable_10'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar10" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=10&amp;root_id=6">PU 195</a>
</li><li id='srtable_22'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar22" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=22&amp;root_id=6">PU 186</a>
</li><li id='srtable_23'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar23" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=23&amp;root_id=6">PU 187.2</a>
</li><li id='srtable_24'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar24" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=24&amp;root_id=6">PU 191</a>
</li><li id='srtable_25'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar25" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=25&amp;root_id=6">PU 550</a>
</li><li id='srtable_26'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar26" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=26&amp;root_id=6">M1T 450.1</a>
</li><li id='srtable_27'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar27" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=27&amp;root_id=6">M1T 455</a>
</li><li id='srtable_28'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar28" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=28&amp;root_id=6">PU 560</a>
</li><li id='srtable_29'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar29" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=29&amp;root_id=6">PU 570</a>
</li><li id='srtable_30'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar30" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=30&amp;root_id=6">PU 580</a>
</li><li id='srtable_33'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar33" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=33&amp;root_id=6">PD 60</a>
</li><li id='srtable_34'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar34" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=34&amp;root_id=6">PD 61</a>
</li><li id='srtable_37'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar37" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=37&amp;root_id=6">QD 191</a>
</li><li id='srtable_38'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar38" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=38&amp;root_id=6">PD 191.1</a>
</li><li id='srtable_42'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar42" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=42&amp;root_id=6">ZDA 31</a>
</li><li id='srtable_43'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar43" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=43&amp;root_id=6">ZDA 2/1</a>
</li><li id='srtable_44'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar44" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=44&amp;root_id=6">STZ</a>
</li><li id='srtable_45'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar45" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=45&amp;root_id=6">PD 194.1</a>
</li><li id='srtable_46'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar46" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=46&amp;root_id=6">PD 194.2</a>
</li><li id='srtable_47'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar47" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=47&amp;root_id=6">PD 194.3</a>
</li><li id='srtable_48'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar48" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=48&amp;root_id=6">PD 194.4</a>
</li><li id='srtable_49'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar49" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=49&amp;root_id=6">PD 194.5</a>
</li><li id='srtable_50'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar50" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=50&amp;root_id=6">REVISOFT</a>
</li><li id='srtable_51'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar51" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=51&amp;root_id=6">LAPLINK</a>
</li><li id='srtable_53'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar53" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=53&amp;root_id=6">USB A-B</a>
</li><li id='srtable_52'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar52" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=52&amp;root_id=6">PU - USB</a>
</li><li id='srtable_39'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar39" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=39&amp;root_id=6">PD 195</a>
</li><li id='srtable_191'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar191" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=191&amp;root_id=6">ELSOFT 1.1</a>
</li><li id='srtable_192'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar192" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=192&amp;root_id=6">ELSOFT 2.0</a>
</li><li id='srtable_193'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar193" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=193&amp;root_id=6">ELSOFT 3.0</a>
</li><li id='srtable_194'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar194" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=194&amp;root_id=6">ZS 12</a>
</li><li id='srtable_195'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar195" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=195&amp;root_id=6">IZO BAT</a>
</li><li id='srtable_196'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar196" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=196&amp;root_id=6">LUX - sonda</a>
</li><li id='srtable_197'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar197" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=197&amp;root_id=6">KM 1</a>
</li><li id='srtable_198'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar198" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=198&amp;root_id=6">RK 3</a>
</li><li id='srtable_199'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar199" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=199&amp;root_id=6">MA 6</a>
</li><li id='srtable_200'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar200" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=200&amp;root_id=6">GP puzdro</a>
</li><li id='srtable_233'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar233" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=233&amp;root_id=6">ALF 10</a>
</li><li id='srtable_234'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar234" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=234&amp;root_id=6">ZEROTEST 46N</a>
</li><li id='srtable_236'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar236" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=236&amp;root_id=6">GIGATEST 500</a>
</li><li id='srtable_237'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar237" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=237&amp;root_id=6">MEDITEST 50</a>
</li><li id='srtable_238'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar238" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=238&amp;root_id=6">REVEX 2051</a>
</li><li id='srtable_245'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar245" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=245&amp;root_id=6">REVEXplus</a>
</li><li id='srtable_246'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar246" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=246&amp;root_id=6">REVEXplusUSB</a>
</li><li id='srtable_298'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar298" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=298&amp;root_id=6">MI 2087-ST</a>
</li><li id='srtable_299'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar299" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=299&amp;root_id=6">MI 2086-ST</a>
</li><li id='srtable_300'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar300" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=300&amp;root_id=6">MI 2086-EU</a>
</li><li id='srtable_301'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar301" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=301&amp;root_id=6">MI 3100</a>
</li><li id='srtable_302'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar302" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=302&amp;root_id=6">MI 3102</a>
</li><li id='srtable_303'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar303" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=303&amp;root_id=6">MA 2082</a>
</li><li id='srtable_304'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar304" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=304&amp;root_id=6">MI 2088</a>
</li><li id='srtable_305'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar305" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=305&amp;root_id=6">MI 2120</a>
</li><li id='srtable_306'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar306" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=306&amp;root_id=6">MI 2123</a>
</li><li id='srtable_307'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar307" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=307&amp;root_id=6">MI 2124</a>
</li><li id='srtable_308'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar308" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=308&amp;root_id=6">MI 3103</a>
</li><li id='srtable_309'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar309" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=309&amp;root_id=6">MI 2077</a>
</li><li id='srtable_310'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar310" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=310&amp;root_id=6">MA 2060</a>
</li><li id='srtable_312'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar312" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=312&amp;root_id=6">MI 2092A</a>
</li><li id='srtable_311'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar311" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=311&amp;root_id=6">MI 2092</a>
</li><li id='srtable_232'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar232" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=232&amp;root_id=6">DIGIOHM 40</a>
</li><li id='srtable_313'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar313" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=313&amp;root_id=6">MI 2130</a>
</li><li id='srtable_314'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar314" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=314&amp;root_id=6">MI 2093</a>
</li><li id='srtable_315'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar315" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=315&amp;root_id=6">MI 2170</a>
</li><li id='srtable_177'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar177" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=177&amp;root_id=6">IZO 1000</a>
</li><li id='srtable_178'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar178" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=178&amp;root_id=6">IZO 2500</a>
</li><li id='srtable_179'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar179" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=179&amp;root_id=6">IZO 1000 PC</a>
</li><li id='srtable_180'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar180" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=180&amp;root_id=6">IZO 2500 PC</a>
</li><li id='srtable_181'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar181" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=181&amp;root_id=6">MINI - 01</a>
</li><li id='srtable_184'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar184" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=184&amp;root_id=6">MINI - 02</a>
</li><li id='srtable_176'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar176" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=176&amp;root_id=6">MINI - 03</a>
</li><li id='srtable_182'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar182" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=182&amp;root_id=6">MPO - 01A</a>
</li><li id='srtable_183'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar183" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=183&amp;root_id=6">MPO - 02</a>
</li><li id='srtable_185'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar185" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=185&amp;root_id=6">UNIMER 02</a>
</li><li id='srtable_186'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar186" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=186&amp;root_id=6">UNITESTER 06</a>
</li><li id='srtable_187'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar187" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=187&amp;root_id=6">UNITESTER 07</a>
</li><li id='srtable_188'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar188" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=188&amp;root_id=6">UNITESTER 07/10</a>
</li><li id='srtable_189'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar189" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=189&amp;root_id=6">UNITESTER 07/Medic</a>
</li><li id='srtable_190'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar190" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=190&amp;root_id=6">MINI - SET</a>
</li><li id='srtable_175'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar175" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=175&amp;root_id=6">UNIMER 08</a>
</li><li id='srtable_596'><span class="textero"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_tovar596" value="on"></span>
<a class="texter" href="http://www.kala-elektro.sk/?sub=kat&amp;tovar_id=596&amp;root_id=6">PD 294.8</a>
</li></ul></td></tr><tr> 
<td colspan="5"> <input type="submit" name="tovar_button_new" value="PRIDAT NOVÝ TOVAR" class="button">
              <input type="submit" name="tovar_button_remove" value="ODSTRÁN OZNACENÉ" class="buttondel"> 
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>            <div align="left">

              <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
                <tr>
                  <td><span class="textb">TIP</span><br>
                    Kliknutím na názov kategórie sa vám zobrazí zoznam podkategórií, 
                    ktoré obsahuje a ktoré môžete dalej editovat.<br>
                    <br>
                    Novú kategóriu vytvoríte kliknutím na PRIDAJ NOVÚ KATEGÓRIU 
                    TOVARU v HLAVNOM MENU.<br>
                    <br>

                    Ak chcete zmenit poradie kategórie, oznacte ju a vyberte PRESUN 
                    OZNACENÉ NAHOR alebo NADOL. Kategóriu tak presuniete úplne 
                    na vrch menu alebo úplne na spodok menu. Ak chcete presunút 
                    kategóriu len o niekolko miest vyberte presunút HORE alebo 
                    DOLE.<br>
                    <br>
                    Kategóriu odstraníte oznacením a kliknutím na ODSTRÁNIT OZNACENÉ. 
                    <font color="#000000"> <strong>POZOR!!! Odstránením kategórie 
                    odstránite aj jej podkategórie a všetok tovar v nich obsiahnutý.</strong></font></td>
                </tr>
              </table>



        <div align="right">&copy; 2006 maks</div></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td width="15%" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

the string itself looks like:

```
str[]=11&str[]=776&str[]=584&str[]=586&str[]=12&str[]=14&str[]=13&str[]=15&str[]=16&str[]=18&str[]=19&str[]=20&str[]=21&str[]=10&str[]=22&str[]=23&str[]=24&str[]=25&str[]=26&str[]=27&str[]=28&str[]=29&str[]=30&str[]=33&str[]=34&str[]=37&str[]=38&str[]=42&str[]=43&str[]=44&str[]=45&str[]=46&str[]=47&str[]=48&str[]=49&str[]=50&str[]=51&str[]=53&str[]=52&str[]=39&str[]=191&str[]=192&str[]=193&str[]=194&str[]=195&str[]=196&str[]=197&str[]=198&str[]=199&str[]=200&str[]=233&str[]=234&str[]=236&str[]=237&str[]=238&str[]=245&str[]=246&str[]=298&str[]=299&str[]=300&str[]=301&str[]=302&str[]=303&str[]=304&str[]=305&str[]=306&str[]=307&str[]=308&str[]=309&str[]=310&str[]=312&str[]=311&str[]=232&str[]=313&str[]=314&str[]=315&str[]=177&str[]=178&str[]=179&str[]=180&str[]=181&str[]=184&str[]=176&str[]=182&str[]=183&str[]=185&str[]=186&str[]=187&str[]=188&str[]=189&str[]=190&str[]=175&str[]=596
```

Where is the problem, pals? Thank you!

Comment: You haven't declared what is not working. You said the ajax is not working, but what does that mean?

Comment: Is `pagesOrder` really a string?  If not, what if you try passing `{poradie: pagesOrder.toString()}`? If it is, how long is it?

Comment: so, can you past the value that is alerted?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen yes, it is. http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-serialize

Comment: have you tried $.get("utried.php", {pagesOrder} ); ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use **POST** instead of **GET**:

the **GET** has limit on browsers 
for example [IE has max length](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427/en-us) 2,083 characters

don't use **GET** for big data.

Comment: Thank you so much, Sir! Just an interesting fact: the data length was 892 chars and it did not work in major browsers like chrome and firefox...

Answer (score 1):

I thing You have to write this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function makeSortable(selector) {
$(selector).sortable({

    update: function(event, ui) {
             var pagesOrder = $(selector).sortable('serialize');
            //or var pagesOrder = $(selector).sortable('serialize',{key:'str[]'});

            alert(pagesOrder);                  
            $.get("utried.php", {pagesOrder} );

       }
   });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    makeSortable("#sortedMenu");  
});
</script>
```

And within your utried.php file, use

```
       $_GET['...']
```